# How would I give a reference of my YouTube channel in the Resume?

Tags: resume

I'm a fresher seeking for a job in Android development and have a YouTube channel on Andrioid development Tutorial.

1. How would I refer the YouTube channel in my résumé?
2. Can I include it under the tiitle of Professional Proficiency?
3. Does it seem to be unprofessional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always worth thinking about what you can do to make your resume stand out against the crowd. My response is below (but not in the exact order you asked).

1. Under the heading "**Professional Profile**" you could include a list of some of the videos you have published to Youtube along with a shortcode link to the those videos. Be sure to provide some context, what are you discussing in the video and why is it relevant to the kinds of roles you are applying for.
2. To share the link just go to the video page and select "Share" (Shown under the video). You will be presented with a url along the lines of https://youtu.be/_jF2QROonTU which you can paste into your resume.

   - For more details, especially about creating a custom URL for your entire channel, see: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968
3. Sharing your passion for the thing you want to do demonstrates professionalism and commitment to your trade craft.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information.It will be good if you suggest a proper format for adding the link.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more professional, and a display of your competency, if you were to secure a custom url (vanity url) - ie a custom domain for your youtube channel. this way it is easier for the resume reader to remember and type it in.  and it looks more professional on the result.  Choose a relatively short domain - and then point it to your youtube channel (I also think youtube has options to do something similar for a premium).

Comment: Could you suggest me a proper format for referring the youtube channel or under what title it should be included?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What title I could give to the referral link or under what title I could include the referal link? Is it belong to Professional Proficiency or some other like any Publications?